# Most efficient way to store generated images?

Tags: php, image, caching

I have an upcoming project where I'll be storing thousands of HD photos on Amazon S3. The problem is, I need both the originals AND a version that includes a watermark. Only the watermarked images will be used on the website. Originals are used for fulfillment.

Is it best if I create the version with the watermark and store on amazon S3, or should I generate the watermarked version on demand from the original, and cache the watermarked image locally? I'm figuring that the trade-off is storage space vs processor usage and load time. I'm not sure what to expect for either.

Comment: You're fishing for opinions, which are explicitly off-topic.

Comment: @MarcB this is a question about efficiency. I'm really hoping NOT to receive opinions. Specifically, this is asking about "Coding techniques" which is on the SO 'tour' list. http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: which is the scarcer (or costlier) resource for you? pick accordingly

Comment: If you're asking about efficiency (which can be a matter of opinion) it is best not to start your question with, "Is it best..." (which is definitely a matter of opinion) @Citizen :)

Comment: Be aware of S3 requests limit: 100req/sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience image processing (particularly of large HD images) is quite slow and memory intensive whereas Amazon S3 storage is quite cheap so I would go for generating resized watermarked images for web display when the data is uploaded and use the optimised images to provide a good user experience.